# how to get 1 row and 6 rows and all rows from feature,regular,free category in product table?

Tags: mysql

```
book_table
id    type        name .... ......
1     feature     book 1 .... ....
2     feature     book 2 ....  ...
n     feature     book n .... ....
----------------------------------
1     regular     book 1 .... ....
2     regular     book 2 ... .....
n     regular     book n .... ...
----------------------------------
1     free        book 1 ....    .
2     free        book 2 .. ......
n     free        book n .........
----------------------------------
```

I want to get

```
id    type        name
1     feature     book 1 .... ... 
2     regular     book 1
..     ......     ......
6     regular     book 6 ........
7     free        all............
```

that's mean 1 row from feature, 6 row from regular, all row from free..

Comment: You may have to do three different queries and union them together to get the results you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

`SELECT * FROM tbl_book WHERE display_date <= CURDATE() AND display_end_date >= CURDATE() AND TYPES='Feature' AND published='1' LIMIT 1 
UNION SELECT * FROM tbl_book WHERE display_date=CURDATE() AND TYPES='Regular' AND published='1' LIMIT 6 
UNION SELECT * FROM tbl_book WHERE TYPES='Free' AND published='1'`

this query already executed properly

Answer (score 0):

You can use variables for this:

```sql
SELECT id, type, name
FROM (
  SELECT id, type, name,
         @rn := IF(@t = type, @rn + 1,
                   IF(@t := type, 1, 1)) AS rn
  FROM mytable
  CROSS JOIN (SELECT @rn := 0, @t = '') AS vars
  ORDER BY type, id) AS t
WHERE (type = 'feature' AND rn = 1) OR 
      (type = 'regular' AND rn <= 6) OR
      (type = 'free')
```

Comment: i have fixed it by three query and then I have created a result array by using three different array....

Comment: @SalmanQuader It should work. There is no need to perform three separate queries. What results do you get?

Comment: I have executed this query....
`SELECT id, types, name
FROM (
  SELECT id, types, name,
         @rn := IF(@t = types, @rn + 1,
                   IF(@t := types, 1, 1)) AS rn
  FROM tbl_book
  CROSS JOIN (SELECT @rn := 0, @t = '') AS vars
  ORDER BY types, id) AS t
WHERE (types = 'Feature' AND rn = 1) OR 
      (types = 'Regular' AND rn <= 6) OR
      (types = 'Free')`
it returns all results

Comment: I have done it by three query and then made an array with them....... 
Now I have an array..
I want to pagination with those all array rows.......
Is it possible or not???